# Do you have available complete guide on installation and administration of FTP Server?

Tags: networking, server, vsftpd

I am new to Ubuntu, our old ftp server  and I am planning to install VSFTPD package. We have already working ftp.****.** ftp site.
Here is my questions:

1. What are the packages do I need to install in Ubuntu prior to installation of VSFTPD?
2. How to connect my local FTP Server to our existing FTP site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide on setting up VSFTPD.  Apt/aptitude should automatically satisfy the necessary dependencies when you install VSFTPD.  When you first install Ubuntu server it should run the tasksel process where you can check "FTP Server" as an option and it'll get it up and running for you out of the box, and all you have to do is lock it down and configure it the way you want.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html

I have to add that if possible you should consider using SFTP instead of FTP for a little extra security.